# Python（Django）のimportの際に使用する.（ドット）がどのように使用されるのか分からない。

Tags: python, python3, django

Djangoのチュートリアルをやっていて気になる箇所があるので質問させて下さい。

DjangoではSECRET_KEYがsettings.pyに直接書かれているので、local_settings.pyを新たに作成してそこにシークレットキーを書き込んみ `from .local_settings import SECRET_KEY as key` でsettings.py側で読み込んでいます。その際に使用する `.` これはlocal_settings.pyとsettings.pyが同じ階層にある事を示していると思っていました。

しかし試しに上記のファイルと同じ階層にtest.pyとtest2.pyを作成して同じようにtest.pyに書いた変数をtest2.pyで読み込んで見ようとしたのですが、`.`を使用すると `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` とエラーになり `.`を外すと上手く読み込まれます。なぜこのようになるのでしょうか？
pythonの `import` がどのように動作しているのかまだ自信がないです。
詳しい方、教えて頂けないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

test.py

```
hello = "hello"
```

test2.py

```
# .testとするとImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
# と表示される。
from test import hello as A

print(A)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ここに答えがあるようですね。パッケージ内の相対インポートという物で使うための物のようです。
[Pythonの相対インポートで上位ディレクトリ・サブディレクトリを指定](https://note.nkmk.me/python-relative-import/)

> パッケージを自作する場合、...途中省略...そのようなときは、相対パスで相対的な位置を指定してインポート（相対インポート）することができる。

> パッケージ内のファイルのように、他のファイルからモジュールとしてインポートされるファイルの中では相対パスを使えるが、pythonコマンドなどで実行されるファイルの中では相対パスは使えないので注意。

つまり単体のスクリプトである`test.py`と`test2.py`はパッケージの構成部品では無いので、`from  import`の先頭に`.`は使えないということなのでしょう。

[6.4.2. パッケージ内参照](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

> 相対 import は現在のモジュール名をベースにすることに注意してください。メインモジュールの名前は常に`"__main__"`なので、Python アプリケーションのメインモジュールとして利用されることを意図しているモジュールでは絶対 import を利用するべきです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 つまり `local_settings.py` djangoのパッケージ構成部品として扱われるような仕様になっているのでしょうか?

Comment: そうですね。それはチュートリアルの最初に書いてあります。[はじめての Django アプリ作成、その 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/3.2/intro/tutorial01/) `mysite/__init__.py: このディレクトリが Python パッケージであることを Python に知らせるための空のファイルです。`

Comment: 今チュートリアルを振り返ってたら書いてありました。`mysite`のフォルダにtest.pyとtest2.py を入れて実行していたのですが、それは実行するパスが `local_settings.py` とは違うからパッケージとして認識されなかったという事でしょうか？

Comment: Djangoプロジェクトのフォルダに入れていたとしても、`test2.py`をDjangoで作ったWebサイトの中の1つのページではなく、単独のスクリプトとして例えば`python test2.py`と言う風に実行していれば、それはパッケージではなくアプリケーションであるということです。

Comment: そうなるんですね。詳しくありがとうございます。スッキリしました。チュートリアルを続けたいと思います。